# How can I optimise wired throughput on my local network router?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, bandwidth, internet-speed

I've got a nominal full-duplex 500Mbit connection through to my ISP (WebPass). When wired directly to their Ethernet port, my machine reliably gets SpeedTest.net results of ~650Mbit down, ~850Mbit up.

However, when I set up a wired connection directly to my recent, high-end wireless router (NETGEAR Nighthawk X8 (R8500)), and then connect the router instead to the WAN, I can't achieve above ~250Mbit/250Mbit.

What can I do to improve my router's *wired* throughput?

Comment: In benchmarks, the R8500 demonstrated a LAN<->WAN NAT performance of over 700Mbps. So your device should be able to do better. Consider upgrading firmware or disabling any unnecessary features.

Comment: Consider turning off NAT if you can get away with it. Or if you only care about performance from a certain machine, make that machine the DMZ host (this often allows the NAT gateway code to do less processing when handling packets between that host and the Internet, which often allows for higher throughput if the router is CPU-constrained). Note that DMZ has security implications, so consider running a personal firewall on that machine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the router is fully-updated — other than NAT, what features might be ‘heavy?’ Can I easily view the usage (CPU, I suppose) or similar? I'm considering installing DD-WRT or something, at this point.

Comment: @Spiff Ah, I wasn't testing from the default-host machine — good idea, I'll try that tonight.